# Предлоги "на" и "в"

Tags: грамотная-речь, предлоги

Какой предлог лучше написать: "определенный опыт работы на/в данном направлении"?

Answer (score 1):

Возможны оба. Но в обычной речи "работать" все-таки скорее "**в направлении**". 
"На направлении" - это из речи военных, отражает статическую ситуацию на каком-то участке фронта, тогда как "в направлении" - движение.